# Post content on Facebook iOS. How to make the app link connect to a URL

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got an issue with an app of mine available on the AppStore.
 In my app you can share contents using the `graph API` given by the `iOS Facebook API`. Everything works perfectly except for the link on the top right angle of the attached image

[image: Screen shot image]

If you click on it guides you through an  [empty facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=303524793035032). I thought it was an automatic link to the itunes application page, but it is something for SSO. Is there a way to point it to another link? I've tried almost everything in the facebook app settings without result.